# How to handle assets like font in a Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, graphicsmagick

I'm working on a Firebase function for drawing text on image. 
First i download locally the image from Cloud Storage and then i use graphics magick to draw text on it and finally upload this new image to Cloud Storage.

**Here the Promise to draw text on image:**

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            gm(tempFilePath)
                .font(Roboto)
                .drawText(10, 10, "My text here")
                .write(newTempFilePath, (err, stdout) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Failed to blur image.', err);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(stdout);
                        resolve(stdout);
                    }
                });
        });
```

**The problem: How to use custom font here ?**

```
.font(Roboto)
```

**Is it possible to handle an asset file as a font file (Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf) in Firebase function ?** 
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the following:

- Get the the Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf font file from here: https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache/roboto.
- Under the functions directory, create a `fonts` folder and paste the `Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf` file there.
- In your code do as follows:

---

```
 gm(tempFilePath)
  .font("./fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf")
  ....
```

---

- Deploy your Cloud Function(s)

Answer (score 1):

Since I write my firebase functions in typescript, my code is compiled to a 'lib' folder. I manually created another subfolder in the 'lib' folder called 'assets'. Then I was able to refer to anything in that folder with the path 'src/assets/...'. (The confusion results from the fact that my firebase functions were compiling to a 'lib' folder but I needed to refer to the file path with 'src' instead of 'lib').
My specific use case was to create a pdf document using pdfkit and I wanted to embed a font file. So with the file now in my 'lib/assets' folder, I could write the following:

```js
doc
    .font('src/assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
    .fontSize(25)
    .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);
```

I'm not sure if this is a best practice, or if there is a way to set up my config to automatically copy files in my source code, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a project structure like this, will not work

```
/functions
    /lib <----- generated by tsc build 
      /fonts <------- manually copied fonts
        myfont.ttf
    /src 
      index.ts
      /fonts. <------- you custom fonts
         myfont.ttf
```

`index.ts`

```
const fonts = 'fonts/myfont.ttf';
```

Solution

```
/functions
    /fonts <------- Creat fonts folder in root
      myfont.ttf
    /lib <----- generated by tsc build 
    /src 
      index.ts
```

`index.ts` will remain the same

```
const fonts = 'fonts/myfont.ttf';
```